# How to prevent Text from shaking when value changes and format double value both sides of the decimal point?

Tags: swift, timer, swiftui, double

I've a countdown timer. When the numbers keep changing, the text moves horizontally and it feels like it is shaking too much, because I'm updating the timer every 0.1 seconds.

How to prevent the text from shaking? Here's full code:

```swift
struct CountDownTimerView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var timer = CountdownTimer(seconds: 15)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(format: "%.1f", timer.time))
            .font(Font.system(size: 144).weight(.light))
    }
}

class CountdownTimer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var time: Double
    
    /// time interval in seconds
    let interval = 0.1
    
    lazy var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { _ in
        self.update()
    }
    
    init(seconds: Double) {
        time = seconds
        timer.fire()
    }
    
    func update() {
        if self.time-interval <= 0 {
            self.time = 0
            timer.invalidate()
        } else {
            self.time -= interval
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the time for the double value 7.329523 and as 07.3. I'm able to achieve either formatting before the decimal point like "07" using `String(format: "%02d", Int(timer.time))` or after the decimal point like "7.3" using `(String(format: "%.1f", timer.time)`. How to format both sides of the decimal point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is it (you have to give full width of output prepending 0, so [0 7 . 3] is four chars, thus:

```
let value: CGFloat = 7.329523
Text(String(format: "%04.1f", value))
```

output

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 12

Answer (score 7):

You should try to use a font with equal spacing for each character, usually named monospaced font.

I have found 2 ways to achieve this with SwiftUI:

#### Monospaced Font

Change the design of the **Font** to monospaced. This will affect how the text looks since it uses a different font design.

`.font(Font.system(size: 144, design: .monospaced).weight(.light))`

#### Adaptive Font

An alternative and better way is to adapt your current **Font** to monospaced digits. You can do so like this:

`.font(Font.monospacedDigit(Font.system(size: 144).weight(.light))())`

Answer (score 0):

**Available from iOS 15.0**

`Text()` has `monospacedDigit()` modifier.

It keeps it's own font design and size and just solves the problem of jumpy text.

```swift
            Text(timerText) // timerText is a string represents timer in the format "hh:mm:ss"
                .monospacedDigit()
```